# Attach JQuery Click Event to Anchor Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-click-event

I have an easy one SO.  Why cant I attach a click event straight to an anchors Id?  I should have pointed out that I am also using JQuery Mobile.

```
            <div id="foobarNavbar" data-role="navbar" style="display:none;">
                <ul>
                    <li><a id="foo" href="#foo" data-icon="plus">New Event</a></li>
                    <li><a id="bar" href="#bar" data-icon="grid">Events</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /foobarNavbar-->
```

I am trying to attach a click event to foo.  This doesn't work:

```
        $('#foo').bind('click', function(e) 
        {   
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("You clicked foo! good work");
        });
```

This does work but gives me the click event for both foo and bar.   Is it not possible to bind to an anchor Id or am I making a rookie error?

```
        $('#foobarNavbar ul li a').bind('click', function(e) 
        {   
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("You clicked foo! good work");
            console.log(e);
        });
```

Comment: The first one [should work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/J7GAA/). Is the DOM ready when the code executes?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cwyRb/ the first one does indeed work.

Comment: It was JQuery Mobile.  The page isn't loaded into the dom on document ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Important: Use $(document).bind('pageinit'), not $(document).ready()
>
> The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the
>   $(document).ready() function so everything will execute as soon as the
>   DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the
>   contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready
>   handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a
>   new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pageinit event.
>   This event is explained in detail at the bottom of this page.

I was trying to bind using document ready instead of pageinit.  The first function

```
$('#foo').bind('click', function(e) 
        {   
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("You clicked foo! good work");
        });
```

works fine when moved to the 'pageinit' event.  I am still not sure, however, why the second code example worked but not the first.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap that code in the document `ready` and it should work if you dont have any other script errors and you have jQuery loaded.

```
$(function(){
   $('#foo').click(function(e) 
   {   
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("You clicked foo! good work");
   });
});
```

Comment: I agree that that's a correct thing to do, but if the second example in the OP worked, it must be the case that he's already using a "ready" handler or something else to ensure the DOM is ready.

Comment: Since jQuery 1.7, you should use `.on(event, handler)` instead of bind

Comment: @Pointy; I agree. I guess some other script errors may be.  Or another possibility is  he clicked the second example after 1 mnt( DOM should have loaded then) and clicked the first one in a hurry !

Comment: It is already wrapped in document ready.  I think the problem may be with JQuery Mobile.  I just moved the binding to "pageinit" event and it works.

Comment: @CrimsonChin: You haven't mentioned that it is jQuery Mobile anywhere int he questions! Always try to use the proper tags also.

Comment: @Shyju Sorry.  I thought it was a(/my) JQuery problem.  You put me on the right tracks.  I will adjust the question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Like that it will work i guess...

```
$('#foobarNavbar').on('click','#foo', function(e) {   
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   console.log("You clicked foo! good work");
   console.log(e);
});
```