# How to unbind click event for anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to work with the following code to unbind click after a certain time for anchor tags.

```
 $('a').click((e)=>{
        x = e.target;
        e.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            unBind(x) }, 500);
});

unBind=(x)=>{
    $(x).unbind('click').click();
}
```

But this is not working. The unbinding is not happening it seems to be. But the code does work if I use class selectors instead.

```
$('.className').click((e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
         setTimeout(function(e){ 
                $('.className').unbind("click").click();
            }, 500);
    })
```

Could someone help me resolving the issue with anchor tag. Thanks!

Edit: Updated the code removing `$(this)` from `setTimeout`

Comment: maybe you don't have a document ready? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227766/2275490

Comment: Make [mre] so we can see ourselves in what case `a` selector does not work and class one does...

Comment: `this` won't be the a-link in the `setTimeout` and it also won't be the a-link in the click handler due to `=>` - in your setTimeout, add `console.log(this)` and it'll probably be `window`

Comment: Little bit confused by your use-case: you want to allow clicks (as many as user can click) for 0.5s then disable all clicks but run one last one (that won't run as clicks are off)?  Bit strange TBH.  If you want a *single click* then use `.one("click", ...` instead, which auto-turns off after... well... one event occurs

Comment: @freedomn-m The usecase is I need to set some datalayer variables on anchor click and once the variable is set it needs to be unbinded and redirected to the href the user clicked.

Comment: So a single click - not as many clicks as you can in 0.5s (which is what you currently have) - why do you have the setTimeout?  Why 500ms?  Handle the redirect-to-href in the datalayer response callback.

Comment: The dataobject gets populated only after a few ms on clicking anchor tag. The settimeout is set to 500ms, to get this object populated and not do the the redirection before that. And this is how I'm populating the object. No response callbacks, just updating the variable.

```formArray['formAbandonment'] = fieldName;```

Comment: And yes you're right, ```$(this)``` is returning window object.

Comment: ```$('a').click((e)=>{
      if ($(".form_container form").length > 0 && fieldName!="") {
          e.preventDefault();
      formArray['formAbandonment'] = fieldName;
   setTimeout(function(e){ $(this).unbind('click').click(); }, 500);
  }
    })
 });```

This is the actual code implementation I was working out. The if condition checks whether it's a form page. If it's a formpage and the user is abandoning the form I need to collect the abandoned field. And that part is working.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate the HTML that you are describing, and I copied your MRE from the first section, added console logging (randomness as an identity for each call), and it seems to work.

```js
 $('a').click((e)=>{
       x = e.target;
       e.preventDefault();
       console.log("click " + Math.random());
       setTimeout(function(){ 
            unBind(x) }, 500);
});

unBind=(x)=>{
    console.log("unbind " + Math.random());
    $(x).unbind('click').click();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="className" href="#f">f</a>
```

Comment: The unbinding is working, but the click is not simulated. Need to click twice on the link.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to have to click on the link twice before the click is unbound?

Answer (score 0):

Tried a little workaround and below is the solution I found.

```
 $('a').click((e)=>{        
            e.preventDefault();
            setTimeout(()=>{window.location.href = $(e.target).attr("href");},500);
    
    });
```